# Infinite while loop Python

Tags: python

A little backstory: I have to make a code in Python that helps the user troubleshoot their phone for a school project. The user must only answer 'yes' or 'no' to the questions the program asks.

The issue I''m having is that inputting something other than 'Yes' or 'No'causes the while loop to loop infinitely instead of displaying just once and moving on to the next question once the user types 'Yes' or 'No'.

The code isn't finished yet, which is why it may look like some of the advice/questions are missing.

EDIT: The code functions properly now! Thanks for your answers, guys! They were really helpful!

```
phoneFault = raw_input("Is your phone physically damaged?")
while phoneFault != "Yes" and phoneFault != "No":
    print("Error; you can only answer 'Yes' or 'No' to the questions.")
if phoneFault == "Yes" or phoneFault == "yes":
    phoneFault = raw_input("Is your phone wet?")
    if phoneFault == "Yes" or phoneFault == "yes":
        phoneFault = raw_input("Are you able to turn it off?")
        if phoneFault == "Yes" or phoneFault == "yes":
            print("Send the phone to the manufacturer and ask if they can fix it.")
        elif phoneFault == "No" or phoneFault == "no":
            print("Dry the phone, and then wait for the phone to run out of power and then restart it.")
```

Comment: You never change the value of `phoneFault` so the while condition never changes. Try adding another phoneFault  = raw_input("Is...") after the while.

Answer (score 2):

```
while phoneFault != "Yes" and phoneFault != "No":
    print("Error; you can only answer 'Yes' or 'No' to the questions.")
```

This line is the culprit. As soon as someone inputs something other than `"Yes"` or `"No"` we enter this while loop. During this while loop, the value of `phoneFault` remains unchanged and therefore we continue to print the error message infinitely.

If you add the ability to change the `phoneFault` value during this while loop, it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you get an infinite loop, look at the condition, then look what might alter that condition.  You probably want something like this, put the `raw_input` inside the loop:

```
phoneFault = None
while phoneFault != "Yes" and phoneFault != "No":
    phoneFault = raw_input("Is your phone physically damaged?")
    print("Error; you can only answer 'Yes' or 'No' to the questions.")
```

That's not very user friendly though.  Having to press < shift > to get a capital Y or N.  You might consider this instead:

```
phoneFault = None
while phoneFault != "yes" and phoneFault != "no":
    phoneFault = raw_input("Is your phone physically damaged (Yes/No)? ").lower()
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want the error printed before re-polling for user input?

Comment: In the 2nd solution I dropped the error message as unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Although you only have two answers per `if` condition, I personally prefer the `if phoneFault in ('Yes','yes'):`membership test. This makes the code more readable. In case you want phoneFault to match anything resembling 'yes' or 'no', you might be interested in regular expressions from the [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module.